# QuickSort Python median-of-three partition

Tags: python, quicksort

I'm doing median-of-three partition of QuickSort but I can't get the code to work. Did I miss some conditions?

```
def quick_sort(a):
    lo,hi = 0,len(a)-1
    pi = partition(a, lo, hi)
    if lo<pi:
    quick_sort(a[lo:pi])
  if pi<hi:
      quick_sort(a[pi:hi])
  return a

def partition(a,lo,hi):
    pi = (lo + hi)//2
    while lo<hi:
        while a[lo]<a[pi]:
            lo+=1
        while a[hi]>a[pi]:
            hi-=1
        if lo<=hi:
            a[lo],a[hi] = a[hi],a[lo]
            lo += 1
            hi -= 1
    return lo
```

Comment: Partition index should be excluded from the range in the recursive calls.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - partition index is included when using Hoare partition scheme, which is what the question's code is a variation of.

Comment: The code is sorting sliced copies of a[], when it should be sorting a[] directly. quick_sort parameters should also be quick_sort(a,lo,hi). There is no median of 3 in the partition code.